# PHP - Setting a specific $variable to NULL

Tags: php, html, classname

So if I have this code in PHP:

```
$class_name;
```

And I want to put it in my markup like this:

```
...
<div class="wrap <?= $class_name ?>"><!-- Content Here --></div>
...
```

How should I declar the variable as NULL in this case? Which one of the following is best:

```
$class_name;
$class_name = "";
$class_name = NULL;
```

EDIT:
I'm using the HTML code above in an external HTML file as a template for 2 of my PHP files (I use `require`).
So in the first php file div.wrap should have only `class="wrap"` and in the other file it has `class="wrap red"`.

Comment: Why would `$class_name;` do anything? I don't see you testing the value of `$class_name` anywhere so what's wrong with `$class_name = NULL;`? Are you using `isset()` or `if ($class_name)` or what?  It's literally what you asked to do. No context, unclear what your criteria of "best" is, voted to close.

Comment: You really should avoid declaring null variables if possible. Of course, sometimes you have to deal with null variables - database values, empty strings that will be concatenated in the future, etc. In those cases, go with what makes sense... In your specific example, I wouldn't even create the variable. Use a test to see if it is set `isset()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the empty string:

`$class_name = "";`

if you intend to use it regularly in the string context. Test with `empty()`.

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" *(an empty string)*
- 0 *(0 as an integer)*
- 0.0 *(0 as a float)*
- "0" *(0 as a string)*
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() *(an empty array)*
- $var; *(a variable declared, but without a value)*

Alot of your decision depends on the required level of precision. For example, in your update there is no trailing whitespace after `class="wrap"` but there is a space between `class="wrap red"`. If you don't mind the trailing whitespace, and you are confident that your variable will always be a string, even if it is an empty string, then you can go along well with your original implementation, and when the variable is empty you will get `class="wrap "`.

I tend to think it good to always be as precise as possible. Thus, I'd put a check in there to prevent the trailing whitespace when you are not concatenating a string..

```
...
<div class="wrap<?= empty($class_name) ? '' : " $class_name" ?>"><!-- Content Here --></div>
...
```

Comment: is_empty is not a real function, and if you mean `empty` be careful of `(string) "0"` testing as "empty" as it may not be desired: http://codepad.org/a6TNnwx7

Comment: I've edted my question. If that's the right answer for it I'll accept it.